# There is a way to make POSTMAN keep sending json files to my application

Tags: json, .net, postman

so i have an application in .NET core with a method that receive a request with a Json, deserialize and save.
What i wanna do is make postman get a json file with a lot of objects and keep sending one by one to my application. Is it possible? Thanks

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example; then, update your question.

Comment: How are you sending the file ? As form data?

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible with the [Postman Collection Runner](https://blog.postman.com/looping-through-a-data-file-in-the-postman-collection-runner/#:%7E:text=Postman%E2%80%99s%20Collection%20Runner%20lets%20you%20run%20all%20the,runner%2C%20you%20can%3A%20Test%20for%20hundreds%20of%20scenarios)

Basically, you create a Runner tab, and then you have the option to select a data file (either `.csv` or `.json`) and loop through the data file for request.

Check the link for their blog post for more details.

- [Collection Run](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/intro-to-collection-runs/)
- [Importing data files](https://learning.postman.com/docs/running-collections/working-with-data-files/)